# Ajax Navigation and form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently my website dynamically loads content using an ajax script.
Here is the script

```js
/***********************************************
* Dynamic Ajax Content- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/
var bustcachevar=1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
var bustcacheparameter=""

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
loadpage(page_request, containerid)
}
if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
var file=arguments[i]
var fileref=""
if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
}
else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
fileref=document.createElement("link")
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
}
}
if (fileref!=""){
document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
}
}
}
```

```html
<p> Hello World! </p>

<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('example.html', 'content');">Form</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

This part work's fine my content is loaded dynamically the problem arises when I attempt to submit a php form inside of the loaded content the whole page simply refreshes I've tried using javascript to stop the page from refreshing but still no luck. I used this form as a test http://www.codingcage.com/2015/06/submit-php-form-without-page-refresh-jquery-ajax.html it functions properly outside of the ajax content but when placed inside the page simply just refreshes! If anyone could give me some insight on how to solve this problem It'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your form is dynamically generated, therefore the event handler doesn't capture your submit event. It happened to me a lot of times and what I did was something like this. I had my selector to the static content. `$("#staticContainer").on("submit","#formId",function(){
});`

Comment: What do you mean your selector? sorry I'm not that flash hot with my javascript

Comment: It is basically something like this `"#staticContainer"`, and `$("#staticContainer")` is the jquery object, and the string inside is what you can call the selector.

Comment: Thanks so much that's sorted my issues